# Laravel Delete / Remove item or product from shopping cart using session

Tags: php, laravel

i have a shopping cart using, i can add product to cart. Now i want to delete and update product form my shopping cart.
In the following codes i'm showing my controller, cart.php, route and shopping cart pages. Now i can add products to cart but i have somes problems with update and delete items form my cart.
Can some help me please..thank you

This the error i get:

```
Call to undefined method App\Cart::remove()
```

Not: I'm using session for this shoppingcart

This is my Cart.php

```
    <?php
namespace App;
/**
 * 
 */
class Cart
{
    public $items = NULL;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart)
    {
        if ($oldCart) {
            
            $this->items        = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty     = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice   = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        }
    }

    public function add($item, $id){
        $storedItem = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $item->price, 'item' => $item];
        if ($this->items) {
            if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
                
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }


}
```

This my productController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Menu;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\AboutUs;
use App\Models\Slider;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Info;
use App\Models\Banner;
use Session;
use App\Cart;

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : NULL;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('products')->with('success', 'Produit ajouté au panier avec succès.');
    }

    public function getCart($slug=NULL){
        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
            return view('shopCart');
        }

        $product                = Product::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $menus                  = Menu::orderBy('id')->get();
        $categoryall            = Category::select('*')
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->get();
        $infos = Info::where('status', 1)->first();

        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        return view('shopCart', [

            'products'      => $cart->items,
            'totalPrice'    => $cart->totalPrice,
            'product'       => $product,
            'menus'         => $menus,
            'categoryall'   => $categoryall,
            'infos'         => $infos,
        ]);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Cart::remove($id);
        return back()->with('success', 'Produit Supprimé du Panier');
    }
```

This my route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CartController;



Route::post('add-to-cart/{id}',                         [HomeController::class, 'getAddToCart'])
->name('addToCart');
Route::get('shoppingCart',                              [HomeController::class, 'getCart'])
->name('shoppingCart');
Route::get('/cart/productDelete',                       [HomeController::class, 'destroy'])
->name('cart.product.delete');
```

This is my shopCart.blade.php

```
@if (Session::has('cart'))
<section class="cart-page pt-10">
    <div class="container-fluid custom-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-8">
                <div class="shopping-cart mt-25">
                    <h4 class="allup-title">Shopping Cart</h4>

                    <div class="shopping-cart-table table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="image">Image</th>
                                    <th class="product">Product</th>
                                    <th class="price">Price</th>
                                    <th class="quantity">Quantity</th>
                                    <th class="total">Total</th>
                                    <th class="delete">Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($products as $product)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="product-image">
                                            <img width="50" src="{{ url('frontend/assets/images/product/'.$product['item']['file']) }}" alt="cart">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="product-title">
                                            <h4 class="title">
                                                <a href="single-product.html">{{$product['item']['name']}}</a></h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="product-price">
                                                <span class="price">{{$product['price']}} €</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="product-quantity">
                                                <div class="quantity mt-15 d-flex">
                                                    <button type="button" class="sub"><i class="fal fa-minus"></i></button>
                                                    <input type="text" name="qty" value="{{$product['qty']}}"/>
                                                    <button type="button" class="add">
                                                        <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="product-total">
                                                <span class="total-amount">€18.90</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="product-delete">
                                                <a href="">
                                                    <button type="submit"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-btn text-right">
                            <form method="POST" action="">
                                @csrf
                                <button class="main-btn" type="submit">Update Cart</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="cart-coupon mt-30">
                                <h5 class="title">Discount Coupon Code</h5>
                                <form action="#">
                                    <div class="single-form coupon-form d-flex flex-wrap">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Coupon Code">
                                        <button class="main-btn">Apply Coupon</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="cart-total mt-30">
                                <div class="sub-total">
                                    <div class="single-total">
                                        <span class="cart-value">Subtotal</span>
                                        <span class="cart-amount">€18.90</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-total">
                                        <span class="cart-value">Shipping Cost</span>
                                        <span class="cart-amount">€3.90</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="total">
                                    <div class="single-total">

                                        <span class="cart-value">Total (Tax.)</span>
                                        <span class="cart-amount">{{$totalPrice}} FCFA</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="single-total">
                                        <span class="cart-value">Taxes</span>
                                        <span class="cart-amount">€0.00</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cart-total-btn text-right">
                                    <a class="main-btn" href="#">Proceed to Checkout</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--====== Cart Part Ends ======-->

    <!--====== Brand Part Start ======-->

    <div class="brand-area pt-80">
        <div class="container-fluid custom-container">
            <div class="row brand-active">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="single-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="assets/images/brand/brand-1.jpg" alt="brand">
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- single brand -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="single-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="assets/images/brand/brand-2.jpg" alt="brand">
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- single brand -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="single-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="assets/images/brand/brand-3.jpg" alt="brand">
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- single brand -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="single-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="assets/images/brand/brand-4.jpg" alt="brand">
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- single brand -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="single-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="assets/images/brand/brand-5.jpg" alt="brand">
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- single brand -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="single-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="assets/images/brand/brand-6.jpg" alt="brand">
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- single brand -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="single-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="assets/images/brand/brand-4.jpg" alt="brand">
                        </a>
                    </div> <!-- single brand -->
                </div>
            </div> <!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </div>

    <!--====== Brand Part Ends ======-->

    <!--====== Features Banner Part Start ======-->

    <section class="features-banner-area pt-80 pb-100">
        <div class="container-fluid custom-container">
            <div class="features-banner-wrapper d-flex flex-wrap">
                <div class="single-features-banner d-flex">
                    <div class="banner-icon">
                        <img src="assets/images/banner-icon/icon1.png" alt="Icon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner-content media-body">
                        <h3 class="banner-title">Free Shipping</h3>
                        <p>Free shipping on all US order</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- single features banner -->
                <div class="single-features-banner d-flex">
                    <div class="banner-icon">
                        <img src="assets/images/banner-icon/icon2.png" alt="Icon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner-content media-body">
                        <h3 class="banner-title">Support 24/7</h3>
                        <p>Contact us 24 hours a day</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- single features banner -->
                <div class="single-features-banner d-flex">
                    <div class="banner-icon">
                        <img src="assets/images/banner-icon/icon3.png" alt="Icon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner-content media-body">
                        <h3 class="banner-title">100% Money Back</h3>
                        <p>You have 30 days to Return</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- single features banner -->
                <div class="single-features-banner d-flex">
                    <div class="banner-icon">
                        <img src="assets/images/banner-icon/icon4.png" alt="Icon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner-content media-body">
                        <h3 class="banner-title">90 Days Return</h3>
                        <p>If goods have problems</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- single features banner -->
                <div class="single-features-banner d-flex">
                    <div class="banner-icon">
                        <img src="assets/images/banner-icon/icon5.png" alt="Icon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="banner-content media-body">
                        <h3 class="banner-title">Payment Secure</h3>
                        <p>We ensure secure payment</p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- single features banner -->
            </div> <!-- features banner wrapper -->
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </section>

    @else
    {{__('Votre Panier est Vide')}}
    @endif
```

Comment: Do you have a `public function deleteCartitem()` in your `HomeController.php`? Your error points to that, but you didn't include that in your code...

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change the route, the route is Route::get('/cart/productDelete',                       [HomeController::class, 'destroy'])
->name('cart.product.delete');

Comment: Where's the `remove` method inside your `Cart` class?

Comment: @LysanderCox i have'nt. Can you explain me please how can i do it ? Thank you

Comment: You haven't written a `remove` method. That's literally what the error is.

Comment: @LysanderCox thank you sir, now i want help to build a remove and update method to my Cart.php. Can some one help me please..? Thank you so much..

Comment: What part is giving you trouble? Just remove the item from the list of items, decrement the total quantity, and subtract the price from the totalPrice attribute.

Comment: destroy method requires an id like the addToCart menthod & the Cart class does not have the remove method as advised above also you are calling the HomeController when you should be calling the ProductController